# how do you develop and test components for all IDE versions?

Tags: delphi

The following question has had me wondering for some time now as to how 3rd party component developers are able to ensure there components are compatible with all the various IDE versions?

I am just a single developer who uses Delphi XE and occasionally Lazarus, if I developed some components in Delphi XE how would I ensure they are compatible up to Delphi XE6 for example, and also compatible with older IDEs?

I don't mean in a coding sense because I believe you use the IFDEF flags when checking the Delphi version numbers. I mean if you don't have access to different Delphi versions how do you test the component?

It is not possible for me right now to purchase XE6 or a new Delphi IDE for a while - if it all, and even if I could I would not have previous IDE's like Delphi 5,6,7 etc.

So how do other component developers do it?

- Purchase all the IDEs? *which seems unlikely*
- Download Trials for the IDEs? *which also seems unlikely*
- Get people to test the component if they have another IDE? *Seems possible*
- Make it Open Source and let others test it? *Also seems possible unless you want it Close Sourced*

What it comes down to is I want to make a few simple components but I want them to be compatible with as many Delphi versions as possible should they ever be released to the public.

I don't have the means to get all the Delphi IDE versions and downloading trials may also not be possible. Even if I bought XE6 or the next release I would not be able to test with Delphi 8 for example.

So, how do 3rd party component developers make there components compatible and tested on various IDEs? Am I missing something obvious here, how can you have access to every Delphi IDE Version?

Comment: You should probably try to become a Technology Partner which will give you access to almost every Delphi version you can think of. The licenses although are only valid through the duration of you partnership.

Comment: The most common approach seems to be to just release to the public, and wait for bug reports to flow in :)

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, isn't that the common approach for all software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a component vendor myself (I am the primary developer of [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org)) who needs to support multiple versions, I can only speak for myself, but here is how I do it:

> Purchase all the IDEs?

If possible, yes.  I have a number of IDE versions installed in VMs, which I use for testing purposes.  And for some versions that I do not have installed, I do have their RTL source code for reference purposes, at least.  On the other hand, as a member of [TeamB](http://www.teamb.com), I get free IDE licenses, which helps. Not everyone can afford to purchase every version, although newer versions do provide free licenses for older versions, so you should take advantage of that.  I recently installed Delphi 7 through this.  If a components works in Delphi 7 and Delphi XE6 then there is a good chance it will work in all versions in between (barring any version-specific RTL bugs, etc).

> Download Trials for the IDEs?

N/A for me, but that might be a viable option for some people.

> Get people to test the component if they have another IDE?

I do this with Indy.  Although I do have several versions, I don't have every version.  Other users who have versions I don't have myself do help.  If nothing else, for setting up version-specific project files and testing install procedures.

> Make it Open Source and let others test it?

This also helps.  If you want to develop closed-source components, you could setup a private repository and give access to select users/volunteers.  Most users want/need source code (to find and fix bugs when used in their projects, to satisfy corporate policy requirements, etc), so you should make sure you offer an option to pay for source code.

Answer (score 3):

When you buy the latest you get access to all the previous versions (from v7 on - thanks Uwe Raabe)

[Previous versions](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/previous-versions)

Comment: Not all, but most - downto Delphi 7.

Comment: That is good, but even if I did buy XE6 I really don't think I would enjoy installing all the previous IDE versions and installing the components and then testing over and over again. Sounds hectic, time consuming and a big frustration waiting to happen.

Comment: Moreover, as far as I remember, you can have only one version installed at a time (but maybe I'm wrong in this).

Comment: That was true of earlier ones I believe, but later ones no - I currently have 2009 and XE6 (trial) installed and it seems fine. If you're doing serious component work though - a lot of VM's is the way to go, so you can go back to start by copying over your Delphi 7 VM for example

Comment: @TLama: Not true. I have had as many as 6 versions installed on the same machine at the same time. (I have four on the machine I'm at now.) As long as they're not installed into the same folder, they're fine.

Comment: @Ken, my bad, I should have been more specific. I was thinking about what allows the license, not about the possibility to have them installed at once.

Comment: @TLama: No problem. :-) My understanding of the license, though, is that the whole purpose of having them is so you can use any and all of them you need at any time. I'll have to look at it again. :-)

Comment: I have Delphi 6, 7, 2005, 2006, 2009, 2010, XE, XE2, XE3, XE4, XE5, XE6 and XE7 installed on one machine for our [www.cartovcl.com](http://www.cartovcl.com) components, and we had D5 in the past too. (XE8 and now 10 Seattle going onto another machine, but they may work on the same machine too). The debuggers of D5/6/7 interfere slightly with each other.

Comment: Still looking for a way to batch compile everthing

Answer (score 2):

I am using the first approach: Buy all versions. I have all Delphi versions back to version 3 (from 1997), but only 6 to XE6 are installed on my machine (with the exception of Delphi 8 which in my opinion should better be forgotten). But of course I didn't buy them all at the same time, I started with Delphi 3 and updated from there on.

Unfortunately it becomes more and more complicated to get older versions installed and running on "modern" operating systems (currently Windows 8.1 so far) so sooner or later I will be forced to switch to virtual machines. Not yet, though. Switching to VMs has the drawback that you can't batch compile using different Delphi versions:

```
call CompileForDelphi6.cmd
call CompileForDelphi7.cmd
etc.
```

like I do for GExperts.

Comment: You could install Hudson / Jenkins CI build agents on these VMs and then configure builds job so that the builds are only executed on the machines which have the matching Delphi version(s) installed

Comment: @mjn: I'll possibly come back to that suggestion once my current solution no longer works. For now it sounds like a lot of work for nothing to gain.

Comment: Ha ha I agree about Delphi 8

Comment: So what goes into your CompileForDelphiXXX.cmd batch scripts? BTW I've been using GExperts for about 9 years now. Awesome, and can't do without it.